# Find a div inside another div using $this and .find

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, append

I have multiple comment forms on one page and after an ajax call need to append the comment to the commentsholder div. But currently its adding it to all, Not sure how to go about only adding it to the current div.

So the comments section looks like this:

```
<div class="commentson">
<div class="commentsholder"> All THE COMMENTS IN HERE </div>
    <form class="addcomment" action="process/addcomment.php" method="post">
        <div class="commentbutton">
        <input type="text" maxlength="250" name="addpostcomment" class="addpostcomment" placeholder="Add Comment... (max 60 characters)" />
        <input type="submit" id="addcommentbutton" class="addcommentbutton" value="Post" disabled/>
        </div>
        <span class="countdownCommentLength"></span>
    </form>
</div>
```

The jQuery append:

```
$( ".commentsholder" ).append("New Comment");
```

There are other forms etc inside the comments divs, but what i need to do is only append the comment to the comments holder that is in the currently in use commentson div.

Comment: what's your whole html structure look like?

Comment: what determines 'the current div'

Comment: Just updated the question with the full html. By current div i mean, the div which contains the form that has been submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` context depends upon where you are trying to do this operation. if you are doing it within the ajax call (`after an ajax call need to append the comment`) back you could do something like this.

```
 $('.addcommentbutton').click(function(){
     var $this = $(this); //cache it here

     //your ajax call
     $.ajax({
        ....
        success: function(){
           $this.closest('.addcomment').prev().append(newComment);
           //or
           //$this.closest('.commentson').find('.commentsholder').append(...);
        }
     });

 });
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Ill make a note to look more into moving around divs etc using this / closest / prev / find etc. Slightly confusing.

Comment: @user2921557 You are welcome. :) On a side note please put your js code as well in the question which will avoid guess work from people trying to understand your issue.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this if `this` context is addcommentbutton

```
$(this).closest('form').prev().append($(this).siblings('.addpostcomment').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add the parent and child in the jQuery selector:

```
$( ".commentson .commentsholder" ).append("New Comment");
```

But if you have multiple .commentsholder then you can use:

```
$(this).parent(".commentsholder ").append("New Comment");
```

$(this) being the current clicked "Button"